# Run a program several times

Tags: python, process

If I run some  program, and in the code I run the program again, in case of failing:

```
if fail == True:
    program()
```

would this new process replace the old one? or stack (in other words, would the old process still be running while along with the new one)?

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: Python interpreters line by line.

Comment: Writing `program()` is not running a program, but calling a function. The function would be called, adding it to the stack, and then the execution would resume at the line after `program()` once the function returns.

Comment: Alright, silly of me to not realize. Thanks for the answer :)